# Usage of .map() and .replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a function which needs to replace all `+` with `,`. Assume the `$(".AdvKeyowrdAND").html` returns `a+b+c+d`. I tried to use `map()` and `replace()` but it only converts the first `+` to `,`. Did I need to use something like `each()`?

```
var array = $(".AdvKeyowrdAND").map(function() {
    return [$(this).html().replace('+',',').split(",")];
}).get();
```

Comment: `.replace(/\+/g, ',');`

Comment: @Tushar wouldnt `/'+'/g` work?

Comment: @guradio `'+` means, one or more single quotes followed by another `'`. `+` is quantifier in regex. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK3lM3/1) and [`'+'` demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK3lM3/2)

Comment: @Tushar i see clarification noted :)

Comment: Can you add related HTML structure too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is not the correct thing to be using for updating the string value. `map()` creates a new array from an existing one, and `replace()` is intended to update the DOM, not a string.

Instead, use a regular expression to update the value, like this:

```js
$(".AdvKeyowrdAND").text(function(i, text) {
  return text.replace(/\+/g, ',');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AdvKeyowrdAND">a+b+c+d</div>
```

Comment: Use `html()` as HTML is not shown and in Question OP has used `html`.

Comment: `text()` is better practice where no HTML tags are be set  - as the OPs question implies - due to it encoding the value

Comment: Yes, but if the element contain HTML elements, but as HTML structure is not shown  `text()` will remove it. Just to be clear, not my downvote.

Comment: @Tushar I agree, although the OP may have larger issues with `html()` where a `+` character is used within the attribute of a tag and is replaced. All guess work at this point though :)

Comment: @Tushar wouldnt using `html()` also remove the current html and be replaced what ever is inside the `html()`?So same thing html will also be lost using `html()` not my down vote either

Comment: Added [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366947/usage-of-map-and-replace#comment66062723_39366947), don't know why this is downvoted. ^1

Comment: @guradio Don't understand your point. But, no, the HTML will not be lost, it'll be updated. The [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) when used with callbacks, as used in this answer, will replace the respective, by the returned string of the callback.